# WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Performing actions on Chrome using WebDriver

I have a webpage with .xqy extension. where I perform some actions and open the first frame. Then after doing some actions on the first frame I open a second frame  and then a third frame.
Now, I need to perform something on the first frame so I close the third frame where selenium's focus is currently on and then the second frame by using the following code:

```
WebDriver dObjExit = driverObj.switchTo().frame(driverObj.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/iframe"))).switchTo().frame(driverObj.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@class='dlg-page']/div[4]/iframe")));
dObjExit.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='modal-footer']/button")).click();
```

Now, I'm just left with the first frame and I use the following code to click upon an element on it:

```
WebDriver dObjExit1 = driverObj.switchTo().parentFrame();
ObjExit1.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='srch-save']")).click();
```

But Selenium throws the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (54, 88). Other
>   element would receive the click:

Any idea about the resolution? Also tried using Actions class but to no avail.

Answer (score 5):

Use JavascriptExecutor to overcome from this issue:-

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("YOUR XPATH"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: what is arguments here ??

Answer (score 1):

You can write 2 methods before line with error, to wait for page to be loaded and all ajax are executed, eg:

```
    public static void waitForPageLoaded() {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectationLoad = new
            ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");
                }
            };
    try {
        Thread.sleep(250);
        WebDriverWait waitForLoad = new WebDriverWait(driver, 33);
        waitForLoad.until(expectationLoad);
    } catch (Throwable error) {
        Assert.fail("Timeout waiting for Page Load Request to complete.");
    }
}

public static void waitForAjaxFinished() {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectationAjax = new
            ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return ((Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
                }
            };
    try {
        Thread.sleep(250);
        WebDriverWait waitForAjax = new WebDriverWait(driver, 33);
        waitForAjax.until(expectationAjax);
    } catch (Throwable error) {
        Assert.fail("Timeout waiting for Ajax Finished to complete.");
    }
}
```